# Updating Tableau table's column descriptions programmatically

Tags: python, tableau-api

I'm using python and TSC (Tableau server client) and trying to update the column description of each table (data table) on the tableau server. Following is my code:

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC

tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth('Token Name', 'Token', 'tableauonline')
server = TSC.Server('serverurl', use_server_version=True)
server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth)

print('Sign in successful')
```

Getting all the tables created on tableau

```
l=list(TSC.Pager(server.tables))
```

Code to select a particular table and update its column description

```
for table in l:
  if (table.name == 'TABLE_NAME'):
        
            print(table.name)
            
            request_options = TSC.RequestOptions(pagesize=1000)
            
            server.tables.populate_columns(table, request_options)
            
            for column in table.columns:
                column.description = column.name
                print(column.id,' ',column.name,' ',column.description)
            break
print(table.name)      
table=server.tables.update(table)
```

The code runs fine without any errors but the descriptions on the server aren't getting updated.